# Explanation of bitwise AND and OR operations

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

```
public class ByteToIntTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte b = -1;
        int i = b;
        System.out.println("i=b: "+i);
        i = b & 0xff;
        System.out.println("i=b&0xff: "+i);
        i = b | 0x00;
        System.out.println("i=b|0x00: "+i);
    }
}
```

The results are:

```
i=b: -1
i=b&0xff: 255
i=b|0x00: -1
```

Why would not `i=b&0xff` and `i=b|0x00` get the same result?

Comment: Your headline should give an idea of what the question will be about. If you look through the list of questions, "How did this happen?" does not really tell you right away what the question is about and whether or not one can answer it with their knowledge..

Comment: This question can be simplified further.

Comment: Also a good question should explain what you are confused about. That means, what other result would you have expected?

Comment: Thanks for your advises. That's the truth spirit and truth attitude.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the results have nothing to do with bytes at all. Quoting [JLS section 15.22.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1):

> When both operands of an operator `&`, `^,` or `|` are of a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive integral type, binary numeric promotion is first performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

As such, since integer literals are `int` ([3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)), the operands (so each `byte`) will be converted to an `int`.

So the question comes down to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(-1 & 0xff); // prints 255, why?
    System.out.println(-1 | 0x00); // prints -1, why?
}
```

`&` performs bitwise AND of the operand values. Consider the following table where each `int` is represented as its binary String:

```
int        -> binary String
-1         -> 11111111111111111111111111111111
0xff (255) -> 00000000000000000000000011111111
0x00 (0)   -> 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Calculating `-1 & 0xff`:

```
  11111111111111111111111111111111
& 00000000000000000000000011111111
= 00000000000000000000000011111111
```

So `-1 & 0xff = 0xff = 255`.

For the second case:

```
  11111111111111111111111111111111
| 00000000000000000000000000000000
= 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

So `-1 | 0x00 = -1`.

Comment: It's really a specific demonstration. My problem solved. Thanks, :?

Comment: @李鸿章 Glad I could help! :). Consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) this answer.